# Django : extract a path from a full URL

Tags: python, django, url

In a Django 1.8 simple tag, I need to resolve the path to the HTTP_REFERER found in the context. I have a piece of code that works, but I would like to know if a more elegant solution could be implemented using Django tools.

Here is my code :

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve, Resolver404

# [...]

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def simple_tag_example(context):
    # The referer is a full path: http://host:port/path/to/referer/
    # We only want the path: /path/to/referer/
    referer = context.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    if referer is None:
        return ''

    # Build the string http://host:port/
    prefix = '%s://%s' % (context.request.scheme, context.request.get_host())
    path = referer.replace(prefix, '')

    resolvermatch = resolve(path)
    # Do something very interesting with this resolvermatch...
```

So I manually construct the string 'http://sub.domain.tld:port', then I remove it from the full path to HTTP_REFERER found in `context.request.META`. It works but it seems a bit overwhelming for me.

I tried to build a `HttpRequest` from `referer` without success. Is there a class or type that I can use to easily extract the path from an URL?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlunparse might be useful, but ahmed's answer is best.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `urlparse` module to extract the path:

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlparse  # Python 3 
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urlparse  # Python 2

parsed = urlparse('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809595')
print(parsed.path)
```

Output:

```
'/questions/32809595'
```

Comment: Note: in python 2, the relevant module is `urlparse`:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

Comment: Why was I looking in the Django modules? Of course Python already has one for that. Thank you very much. I need to sleep ;)

Comment: python3: 
`import urllib`
`urllib.parse.urlparse('urlhere')`